# How would I exponentiate each element of a non-square matrix?

Tags: matlab, exponentiation

I have a matrix with dimensions 512 x 683 and I'm looking to gamma transform it by raising it to .8 and 1.2 seperately. Obviously you cannot raise nonsquare matrices to powers, so I was wondering how would I go about raising each element of the matrix to the .8th power and the 1.2 power.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element wise:

```
newMat1 = oldMat.^0.8;
```

and

```
newMat2 = oldMat.^1.2;
```

Comment: And in general putting a dot in front of an operator changes the meaning from a matrix operator to treating the matrix as a collection of unrelated values, each of which is processed separately.  e.g. `.*` performs element-wise multiplication on two matrices of identical size, instead of matrix multiply on two matrices which have a shared bound.

Comment: @Nick im geting an error stating "integers can only be raised to positive integral powers", any ideas on how to get around that

Comment: @user2475404 Convert it to a `double` type first. `double(oldMat).^0.8`. Most MATLAB operations create `double` types by default, but it sounds like you've got a matrix of integer types. As a result, MATLAB refuses to raise them to a power that would change the type. Explicit conversion to `double` type should fix it.